# How can I put greek references first and then the english?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to write the bibliography of my Master thesis. My.bib file is this

```
@misc{study1,
title={The economic effects of the coronavirus around the world},
url={https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2020/02/coronavirus-economic-effects-global-economy-trade-travel/},
journal={World Economic Forum},
author={Hutt, Rosamond},
year={2020},
month={Feb}}

@misc{study2,
place={Brussels},
title={The impact of the COVID-19 crisis on poverty and social exclusion in Bulgaria},
institution={ESPN},
author={Bogdanov, George},
year={2020},
note = {\url{https://ec.europa.eu/social/BlobServlet?docId=22934&langId=en}}}

@misc{study3,
title={The Covid-19 recession in France: The trough is behind us, but let’s stay vigilant}, 
url={https://cepr.org/voxeu/columns/covid-19-recession-france-trough-behind-us-lets-stay-vigilant},
journal={CEPR},
author={Ferrara, Laurent and Mignon, Valerie},
year={2021},
month={Nov}}

@misc{study4,
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.3\% EU at 6.5\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10662618/3-01042020-AP-EN.pdf/be3d73ee-6715-824b-2c23-f0512f12bdc6?t=1585657691000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020}}

@misc{study5,
title={Online dashboard and data analysis approach for assessing COVID-19 case and death data},
author={Florez, Hector and Singh, Sweta},
journal={F1000Research},
volume={9}, year={2020},
publisher={Faculty of 1000 Ltd},
note ={\url{https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7450472/}}}

@misc{study6,
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.3\% EU at 6.6\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10294960/3-03062020-AP-EN.pdf/b823ec2b-91af-9b2a-a61c-0d19e30138ef?t=1591123422000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020},
month={Jun}}

@misc{study7,
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.9\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10568643/3-01092020-BP-EN.pdf/39668e66-2fd4-4ec0-9fd4-4d7c99306c98?t=1598882965000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020},
month={Sep}}

@misc{study8,
title={Assessing the impact of COVID-19 on Africa’s economic development},
author={Gondwe, Grace},
booktitle={United Nations Conference on Trade and Development},
volume={3},
year={2020},
note = {\url{https://unctad.org/system/files/official-document/aldcmisc2020d3_en.pdf}}}

@misc{study9,
title = {Analyzing COVID-19 pandemic for unequal distribution of tests, identified cases, deaths, and fatality rates in the top 18 countries},
journal = {Diabetes & Metabolic Syndrome: Clinical Research & Reviews},
volume = {14},
number = {5},
pages = {953-961},
year = {2020},
issn = {1871-4021},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dsx.2020.06.051},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1871402120302204},
author = {Shahbaz A. Shams and Abid Haleem and Mohd Javaid},
keywords = {Country-wise analysis, COVID-19, Life expectancy: Pandemic}}

@misc{study10,
author={Wickham, Hadley and Sievert, Carson and Springer},
title={Ggplot2 : Elegant Graphics For Data Analysis},year={2016},
url = {https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org}}

@misc{study11,
author = {Hadley Wickham and Jim Hester and Jennifer Bryan},
title = {readr: Read Rectangular Text Data},
year = {2022},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=readr}}

@misc{study12,
author = {Hadley Wickham and Romain François and Lionel Henry and Kirill Müller},
title = {dplyr: A Grammar of Data Manipulation},
year = {2022},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dplyr}}

@misc{study13,
author = {Ron Ammar},
title = {randomcoloR: Generate Attractive Random Colors},
year = {2019},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=randomcoloR}
}

@book{book1,
title={Πολυμεταβλητή Στατιστική Ανάλυση},
ISBN={9603515949},
publisher={Εκδόσεις Σταμούλη},
author={Καρλής, Δημήτρης},
year={2005}}

@book{book2,
title = {Επιχειρηματική ευφυΐα και εξόρυξη δεδομένων},
editor = {Παπαβασιλείου, Σπυρίδων}, pages = {261-287},
publisher={Εκδόσεις Kallipos, Open Academic Editions},
author={Κύρκος, Ευστάθιος},
chapter = {11. Ανάλυση Συστάδων},
ISBN={978-960-603-109-0}, year={2015}}

@misc{study14,
author = {Κυριακή Ι. Ιωαννίδου},
title = {Διαχωριστική Ανάλυση και εφαρμογές},
year = {2011},
note = {Προπτ/κή διπλ. εργάσ. Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών και Φυσικών Επιστημών},
url = {https://dspace.lib.ntua.gr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/5414/\%CE\%B9\%CF\%89\%CE\%B1\%CE\%BD\%CE\%BD\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B4\%CE\%BF\%CF\%85\%CE\%BA_\%CE\%B4\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B1\%CF\%87\%CF\%89\%CF\%81\%CE\%B9\%CF\%83\%CF\%84\%CE\%B9\%CE\%BA\%CE\%AE.pdf?sequence=3}}

%study14 is a greek reference

@misc{study15,
author = {Στρατινάκης, Νικόλαος},
title = {Εφαρμοσμένη Ανάλυση Συστάδων },
year = {2018},
url = {https://dias.library.tuc.gr/view/manf/79057},
note = {Μεταπτ/κή διπλ. εργασ. Πολυτεχνείο Κρήτης Σχολή Μηχανικών Παραγωγής και Διοίκησης Π.Μ.Σ Εφαρμοσμένα Μαθηματικά για μηχανικούς}}

%study15 is a greek reference

@misc{study16,
author = {Καλλιόπη, Παπούλια},
title = {Μέθοδοι Πολυμεταβλητής Ανάλυσης Επιχειρηματικών Δεδομένων},
url ={https://dione.lib.unipi.gr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/unipi/12905/\%CE\%94\%CE\%B9\%CF\%80\%CE\%BB\%CF\%89\%CE\%BC\%CE\%B1\%CF\%84\%CE\%B9\%CE\%BA\%CE\%AE\%20\%CE\%95\%CF\%81\%CE\%B3\%CE\%B1\%CF\%83\%CE\%AF\%CE\%B1\%20\%CE\%A0\%CE\%B1\%CF\%80\%CE\%BF\%CF\%8D\%CE\%BB\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B1\%20\%CE\%9A\%CE\%B1\%CE\%BB\%CE\%BB\%CE\%B9\%CF\%8C\%CF\%80\%CE\%B7-MES18020.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y},
note = {Μεταπτ/κή διπλ. εργασ. Πανεπιστήμιο Πειραιώς Τμήμα Στατιστικής και Ασφαλιστικής Επιστήμης Π.Μ.Σ Εφαρμοσμένη Στατιστική}
}

%study16 is a greek reference

@misc{study17,
title = {Our World in Data},
url = {https://github.com/owid},
author = {GitHub}}
```

My .tex file is the following

```
\documentclass[inscr,ack,preface]{dithesis}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib} %my .bib file is called references.bib

%My document

% manually include the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{references}
% include it also in ToC (do sth on your own)
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Βιβλιογραφία}

\chapter*{\bibname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax % Disable page breaks within this group
\printbibliography[type=book, title={Βιβλία}]
\printbibliography[type=misc, title={Διαδικτυακή βιβλιογραφία}]
\endgroup

%\nocite{*}

\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I want first the greek references in the "group" with title "Διαδικτυακή βιβλιογραφία" and after the greek references I want to put the english references. You can see in   [the picture I attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2IDo.png) that the english references in the "group" with title "Διαδικτυακή βιβλιογραφία" are first and the greek references are second. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Your code seems to not compile. Possibly, the sorting order of the entries is alphabetical, so it starts with Latin alphabet and then adds non-latin entries. Try setting greek as main document language (if it is the case) with babel or polyglossia. And have a look at `sortlocale` option of `biblatex`

Answer (score 0):

I found that I should use the `sortkey` argument with the value {A} in the references I want first and the value {B} in the references I want second. I will put the code of .bib file

```
@misc{study1,
sortkey = {B},
title={The economic effects of the coronavirus around the world},
url={https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2020/02/coronavirus-economic-effects-global-economy-trade-travel/},
journal={World Economic Forum},
author={Hutt, Rosamond},
year={2020},
month={Feb}}

@misc{study2,
sortkey = {B},
place={Brussels},
title={The impact of the COVID-19 crisis on poverty and social exclusion in Bulgaria},
institution={ESPN},
author={Bogdanov, George},
year={2020},
note = {\url{https://ec.europa.eu/social/BlobServlet?docId=22934&langId=en}}}

@misc{study3,
sortkey = {B},
title={The Covid-19 recession in France: The trough is behind us, but let’s stay vigilant},
url={https://cepr.org/voxeu/columns/covid-19-recession-france-trough-behind-us-lets-stay-vigilant},
journal={CEPR},
author={Ferrara, Laurent and Mignon, Valerie},
year={2021}, month={Nov}}

@misc{study4,
sortkey = {B},
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.3\% EU at 6.5\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10662618/3-01042020-AP-EN.pdf/be3d73ee-6715-824b-2c23-f0512f12bdc6?t=1585657691000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020}}

@misc{study5,
sortkey = {B},
title={Online dashboard and data analysis approach for assessing COVID-19 case and death data},
author={Florez, Hector and Singh, Sweta},
journal={F1000Research},
volume={9},
year={2020},
publisher={Faculty of 1000 Ltd},
note ={\url{https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7450472/}}}

@misc{study6,
sortkey = {B},
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.3\% EU at 6.6\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10294960/3-03062020-AP-EN.pdf/b823ec2b-91af-9b2a-a61c-0d19e30138ef?t=1591123422000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020},
month={Jun}}

@misc{study7,
sortkey = {B},
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.9\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10568643/3-01092020-BP-EN.pdf/39668e66-2fd4-4ec0-9fd4-4d7c99306c98?t=1598882965000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020},
month={Sep}}

@misc{study8,
sortkey = {B},
title={Assessing the impact of COVID-19 on Africa’s economic development},
author={Gondwe, Grace},
booktitle={United Nations Conference on Trade and Development},
volume={3},
year={2020},
note = {\url{https://unctad.org/system/files/official-document/aldcmisc2020d3_en.pdf}}}

@misc{study9,
sortkey = {B},
title = {Analyzing COVID-19 pandemic for unequal distribution of tests, identified cases, deaths, and fatality rates in the top 18 countries},
journal = {Diabetes & Metabolic Syndrome: Clinical Research & Reviews},
volume = {14},
number = {5},
pages = {953-961},
year = {2020},
issn = {1871-4021},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dsx.2020.06.051},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1871402120302204},
author = {Shahbaz A. Shams and Abid Haleem and Mohd Javaid},
keywords = {Country-wise analysis, COVID-19, Life expectancy: Pandemic}}

@misc{study10,
sortkey = {B},
author={Hadley Wickham},
title={Ggplot2 : Elegant Graphics For Data Analysis},
year={2016},
url = {https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org}}

@misc{study11,
sortkey = {B},
author = {Jim Hester},
title = {readr: Read Rectangular Text Data},
year = {2022},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=readr}}

@misc{study12,
sortkey = {B},
author = {Lionel Henry},
title = {dplyr: A Grammar of Data Manipulation},
year = {2022},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dplyr}}

@misc{study13,
sortkey = {B},
author = {Ron Ammar},
title = {randomcoloR: Generate Attractive Random Colors},
year = {2019},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=randomcoloR}}

@book{book1,
title={Πολυμεταβλητή Στατιστική Ανάλυση},
ISBN={9603515949},
publisher={Εκδόσεις Σταμούλη},
author={Καρλής, Δημήτρης},
year={2005}}

@book{book2,
title = {Επιχειρηματική ευφυΐα και εξόρυξη δεδομένων},
editor = {Παπαβασιλείου, Σπυρίδων},
pages = {261-287},
publisher={Εκδόσεις Kallipos, Open Academic Editions},
author={Κύρκος, Ευστάθιος},
chapter = {11. Ανάλυση Συστάδων},
ISBN={978-960-603-109-0},
year={2015}}

@misc{study14,
sortkey = {A},
author = {Κυριακή Ι. Ιωαννίδου},
title = {Διαχωριστική Ανάλυση και εφαρμογές},
year = {2011},
note = {Προπτ/κή διπλ. εργάσ. Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών και Φυσικών Επιστημών},
url = {https://dspace.lib.ntua.gr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/5414/\%CE\%B9\%CF\%89\%CE\%B1\%CE\%BD\%CE\%BD\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B4\%CE\%BF\%CF\%85\%CE\%BA_\%CE\%B4\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B1\%CF\%87\%CF\%89\%CF\%81\%CE\%B9\%CF\%83\%CF\%84\%CE\%B9\%CE\%BA\%CE\%AE.pdf?sequence=3}}

@misc{study15,
sortkey = {A},
author = {Στρατινάκης, Νικόλαος},
title = {Εφαρμοσμένη Ανάλυση Συστάδων },
year = {2018},
url = {https://dias.library.tuc.gr/view/manf/79057},
note = {Μεταπτ/κή διπλ. εργασ. Πολυτεχνείο Κρήτης Σχολή Μηχανικών Παραγωγής και Διοίκησης Π.Μ.Σ Εφαρμοσμένα Μαθηματικά για μηχανικούς}}

@misc{study16,
sortkey = {A},
author = {Καλλιόπη, Παπούλια},
title = {Μέθοδοι Πολυμεταβλητής Ανάλυσης Επιχειρηματικών Δεδομένων},
year = {2020},
url ={https://dione.lib.unipi.gr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/unipi/12905/\%CE\%94\%CE\%B9\%CF\%80\%CE\%BB\%CF\%89\%CE\%BC\%CE\%B1\%CF\%84\%CE\%B9\%CE\%BA\%CE\%AE\%20\%CE\%95\%CF\%81\%CE\%B3\%CE\%B1\%CF\%83\%CE\%AF\%CE\%B1\%20\%CE\%A0\%CE\%B1\%CF\%80\%CE\%BF\%CF\%8D\%CE\%BB\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B1\%20\%CE\%9A\%CE\%B1\%CE\%BB\%CE\%BB\%CE\%B9\%CF\%8C\%CF\%80\%CE\%B7-MES18020.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y},
note = {Μεταπτ/κή διπλ. εργασ. Πανεπιστήμιο Πειραιώς Τμήμα Στατιστικής και Ασφαλιστικής Επιστήμης Π.Μ.Σ Εφαρμοσμένη Στατιστική}}

@misc{study17,
sortkey = {B},
title = {Our World in Data},
url = {https://github.com/owid},
author = {GitHub}}
```

Then I compiled multiple times and it worked.